# Invariant Subspace Problem

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, functional-analysis, open-problem

Louis de Branges  had a paper on his [homepage](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~branges/site//Papers) claiming a solution for the [Invariant Subspace Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem).

But I don't see that paper anymore, though he still has a "proof" of  Riemann Hypothesis on his website.

Does anyone know whether he actually admitted his proof of the Invariant Subspace Problem was wrong? Or someone pointed that out?

His proposed proof of the RH has been on his website for many years now, and yet no one has pointed out an error.

Comment: This is also a bit of a reference request, isn't it? I've added that tag.

Comment: I think that there are people who have pointed out an error, maybe you have not heard about it. Unfortunately, I can not recall any names. I would also like to point out that no one has given him the millennium prize for solving RH.

Comment: About the RH, the latest version of his paper seems not to have been subject to a careful reading, since it is extremely demanding. But experts believe that his approach is unlikely to be right. See "The Strange Case of Louis de Branges" by Karl Sabbagh.